# can't open the google analytics api page for android

Tags: android, api, analytics

I want to add google analytics api into our android app. But when I tried to open the page as shown below, it occured a 404 error.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/integrate

Please tell me what's wrong and how to go ahead.

Thanks.

BR, Sunny

Comment: do you mean this page ??
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you referred to some old link.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/
This one should help you.
Simply setup your project and you can start analysing data in few minutes. You can define your own events too.